# What is Unicode? and how Encoding works?

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, character

Few hours before I was reading a c programming book. While I was reading the book I came across these words, Character encoding and Unicode. Then I started googling for the information about Unicode. Then I came to know that Unicode character set has every character from every language and **UTF-8**,16,32 can encode the characters listed in **unicode** character set.

but I was not able to understand how it works. 
Does unicode depends upon the operating systems? 
How it is related to softwares and programs? 
Is UTF-8 is a software that is installed on my computer when i installed operating system? 
or Is it related to hardware? 
and how a computer encodes the things?

I have found it so much confusing. Please answer me in detail.
I am new to these things, so please keep that in mind while you give me the answer.

thank you.

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: 1. Read Joel. 2. Read this: http://utf8everywhere.org

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have written about this extensively in [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/). Here some highlights:

- encodings are plentiful, encodings define how a "character" like "A" can be *encoded* as bits and bytes
- most encodings only specify this for a small number of selected characters; for example all (or at least *most*) characters needed to write English or Czech; single byte encodings typically support a set of up to 256 characters
- Unicode is one large standard effort which has catalogued and specified a number ⟷ character relationship for virtually all characters and symbols of every major language in use, which is hundreds of thousands of characters
- UTF-8, 16 and 32 are different sub-standards for how to encode this ginormous catalog of numbers to bytes, each with different size tradeoffs
- software needs to specifically support Unicode and its UTF-* encodings, just like it needs to support any other kind of specialized encoding; most of the work is done by the OS these days which exposes supporting functions to an application

Comment: Thanks, the mentioned article is easier to understand than Joel Spolsky's.